# Select rows with any member of list of substrings in string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reportbuilder

In a Micrososft SQL Server table I have a column with a string.

Example:

```
'Servernamexyz.server.operationunit.otherstuff.icouldnt.predict.domain.domain2.domain3'
```

I also have a dynamic list of substrings

Example:

```
('icouldnt', 'stuff', 'banana')
```

I don't care for string manipulation. The substrings could also be called:

```
('%icouldnt%', '%stuff%', '%banana%')
```

What's the best way to find all rows where the string contains one of the substrings?

Solutions that are not possible:

- multiple OR Statements in the WHERE clause, the list is dynamic
- external Code to do a "for each", its a multi value parameter from the reportbuilder, so nothing useful here
- changing the database, its the database of a tool a costumer is using and we can't change it, even if we would like... so much

I really cant believe how hard such a simple problem can turn out. It would need a "LIKE IN" command to do it in a way that looks ok. Right now I cant think of anything but a messy temp table.

Comment: so you want to find out whether the "dynamic list of substrings" exist in the column?

Comment: I want to Select the rows that have any of the substrings in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql)

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (Col1 NVARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO @tab (Col1)
VALUES (N'Servernamexyz.server.operationunit.otherstuff.icouldnt.predict.domain.domain2.domain3' )

;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT 'icouldnt' Strings
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'stuff'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'banana'
)
SELECT
    T.*, X.Strings
FROM @tab   T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT X.Strings FROM cteX X) X
WHERE CHARINDEX(X.Strings, T.Col1) > 1
```

Output

[image]

EDIT - using an unknown dynamic string variable - @substrings

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (Col1 NVARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO @tab (Col1)
VALUES (N'Servernamexyz.server.operationunit.otherstuff.icouldnt.predict.domain.domain2.domain3' )

DECLARE @substrings NVARCHAR(200) = 'icouldnt,stuff,banana'

SELECT
    T.*, X.Strings
FROM @tab   T
CROSS APPLY 
(   --dynamically split the string
    SELECT Strings = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
    FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
        + REPLACE(@substrings, ',', '</i><i>') 
        + '</i>').query('.')
    ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
) X
WHERE CHARINDEX(X.Strings, T.Col1) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response. This, or something like this, is the solution i would prefer when the list of substrings wasnt dynamic. But it is. I dont know the substrings until they are selected by the user.

Comment: How is this list of dynamic substrings passed to the database?

Comment: I can pass it as a multi value parameter directly from the report builder. As far as Im aware thats basically a list in the mentioned Format: ('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4'). I could als transform it to a single string of various shapes before passing it. Like 'string1,string2,string3,string4' or  '%string1%,%string2%,%string3%,%string4%'

Comment: Tested it on the live Server. Still works, but the performance is an issue. No idea if there is any way to improve it. This gives me some very useful hints anyway.

Comment: Sadly I cant. Would it make any difference if I could somehow make a list of all possible substrings? It is possible, ist just a lot of them (about 300 i guess.)

Comment: without the plan, number of records in table, indices etc I can't help with performance improvement.